# how to manipulate data in ngrx effect and return it as payload to action?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

i have ngrx effect that makes post to api and get response.
when i get the response i want to create instance of interface of this data and dispatch success action with this as payload.
the problem is that i get instead the success action the fail action.

[image]
[image]
[image]

but when i do it this way and dispatching success action with the data i get success as expected
[image]
what is the issue here?

Comment: What error are you getting? The code looks ok, so it could be that one of the array properties you use in data when initializing EstateOwner is null?

Comment: there is no error. just in the first example when i create object and dispatch success it not reaches there, it goes directly to the fail even that the response is 201.  but when i dispatch success with the original data returned from the api (the second screenshot) the correct action is dispatched (success)

Comment: What does your service look like?